# How do I output everything in the log on Android without truncation?

Tags: android

I would like to output a lot of data to my log on Android...but it's truncating the data.

How do I prevent it from truncating my logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logcat truncates data after 4000 characters so you could write it out in chunks:

```
public static final int LOGCAT_MAX_LINE_LIMIT = 4000;

public static final String TAG = "log_tag";

private void showLog(String message) {
        if (message.length() > LOGCAT_MAX_LINE_LIMIT) {
            int chunkCount = message.length() / LOGCAT_MAX_LINE_LIMIT;
            for (int i = 0; i <= chunkCount; i++) {
                int max = LOGCAT_MAX_LINE_LIMIT * (i + 1);
                if (max >= message.length()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, message.substring(LOGCAT_MAX_LINE_LIMIT * i));
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, message.substring(LOGCAT_MAX_LINE_LIMIT * i, max));
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, message);
        }
    }
```