# Android BufferedReader does not read the whole response

Tags: java, android, url, bufferedreader

I have a problem with reading a ULR response. On Android it only reads around the half of the response.

If I use the same code in a normal Java project everything works fine.

```
    try {
        String _output = null;
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        StringBuilder everything = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            everything.append(line);
        }
        _output = everything.toString();

        buffer.close();

        System.out.print(_output);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you know that it's only half of the response? If you rely on what is printed with `System.out.println()` then you should be aware that Logcat has a limitation that prevents it from printing more than 4,000 characters. Anything after that is truncated. To check how much of the response you have, you could print `everything.length()`first, ot see if you are in that situation.

You can look at [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28462461/524900) on SO for reference, but there are many others.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this was the problem :D